# "You cannot assign value to this object." with new record

Tags: ms-access

I have a VERY peculiar problem. When a new record is created and I want to select a Customer_ID from ComboBox, after selection it throws me the above mentioned error. However, it actually gets assigned (ie. everything works as it should, but for the error).

Is there a way to bypass/disable this error?

P.S.: This is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCqOO.jpg

Edit: I have located the error and it seems that it comes down to: trying to assign a value into a record that is not "confirmed" yet. That means it has no (auto generated) ID yet. Basically, how would I go about `confirming` that I want to create the said error?

My code (to create a new record) is as follows:

```
'some other irrelevant code
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.subOrders_for_main_overview.Form.Recordset
rs.AddNew
'some other irrelevant code
```

This creates a new blank record.

Comment: Is there any VBA triggering this error?

Comment: No. I made a gif recording the behaviour: http://g.recordit.co/h6WlMBNyFS.gif

Comment: Basically the button I click is a VBA code to create a new record. Then the comboBox is assigning the "Customer_ID" to this new record. It goes through, as you see, in the gif, but the error is still showing up now and then.

Comment: I couldn't access your gif. What kind of dialogue box do you get? Is it "Ok" only, or do you get the option to debug?

Comment: Just copy the address and paste it into another window (I think stackoverflow blocks the access). Otherwise yes, it is "Ok" only window (error is not associated with custom VBA error handling but some default access error).

Comment: This is the actual error message: http://imgur.com/rTQC9za  (you could add that to your description).

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused when you try to assign a value to a BOUND control.  If the control/object is supposed to be UNBOUND, go back to its property and confirm it.  You may get a surprise!  I was working with the VB behind a form and suddenly I started getting a "can't find table" and "can't assign a value" to several, but not all, of the controls on the form.  For reasons that I have not determined, the form's control source acquired a query that it was never bound to, and 5 random controls had their control.name as their control source.  Once I removed them, the form was ok